# how to create dictionary words with random letters in android?

Tags: android, dictionary, cpu-word

I am creating a small word game for my self.I am generating random letters.

Here code for generating random letters:

```
      //GENERATE RANDOME LETTERS
     mRnd = new Random();
    mLetters = 25;

    String randomLetters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

    for ( n=0; n<mLetters; n++)
      System.out.println("Random letters"+randomLetters.charAt(mRnd.nextInt(randomLetters.length())));
```

Here i want how to generate some meaning full words with this random letters Like(CAT,BAT,RAT).

Comment: you should have database dictionary itself. Java doesnt understand words like cat,bat,rat it is language... and i dont think that there are algorithms that does it..

Comment: ok.I want some meaning full words.

Comment: you should have a database of words, in your case database of `ENGLISH Words` then from randomly generated letters, make some compares and find out which words can be built by that letters

Answer (score 0):

You should download a dictionary and load it at runtime. There is no code to validate if the word exists, you can only compare it to a known list.

Here you can download a English dictionary: http://www.curlewcommunications.co.uk/wordlist.html

Comment: This helped me too but had to do some changes according to need. This seems best solution, to load dictionary at run time.